# How to loop a function and generate 3 separate lists in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I would like to download daily prices for three months with the BatchGetSymbols function. My goal is to automate this process, so that i don't have to change the code up whenever i decide to use a different time period (eg number of months). The BatchGetSymbols function returns a list.

The for loop looks like this:

```
holdingperiod <- seq(last.date, last.date %m+% months(3), by = "months")
names <- cbind(c("w.one","w.two","w.three"))

for(i in 1 : length(names)){
  names[i] <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = winnertickers$`S&P500 Ticker`, first.date = holdingperiod[i], last.date = holdingperiod[i+1], do.cache = FALSE, freq.data = "daily")
}
```

Whenever i run this code, it gives me the error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In names[i] <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = winnertickers$`S&P500 Ticker`,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In names[i] <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = winnertickers$`S&P500 Ticker`,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In names[i] <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = winnertickers$`S&P500 Ticker`,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

What i want the for loop to do is to produce the equivalent outcome to the following lines of code:

```
w.one <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = winnertickers$`S&P500 Ticker`, first.date = holdingperiod[1], last.date = holdingperiod[2], do.cache = FALSE, freq.data = "daily")
w.two <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = winnertickers$`S&P500 Ticker`, first.date = holdingperiod[2], last.date = holdingperiod[3], do.cache = FALSE, freq.data = "daily")
w.three <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = winnertickers$`S&P500 Ticker`, first.date = holdingperiod[3], last.date = holdingperiod[4], do.cache = FALSE, freq.data = "daily")
```

That means i would like 3 lists that have the names w.one, w.two and w.three. Does anybody have an idea how i could do that/ what to write instead of names[i]? Please let me know if any additional information is required. I appreciate every help. Best regards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this you can use the `assign` function:

```
for(i in 1 : length(names)){
    assign(names[i], BatchGetSymbols(tickers = "FB", first.date = holdingperiod[i], last.date = holdingperiod[i+1], do.cache = FALSE, freq.data = "daily"))
}
```

But perhaps it would be more helpful to have have a list (e.g. `w`) containing the three downloaded data sets:

```
w <- lapply(
    1:3, 
    function(i) {
        BatchGetSymbols(tickers = "FB", first.date = holdingperiod[i], last.date = holdingperiod[i+1], do.cache = FALSE, freq.data = "daily)
    }
)
```

This makes it possible to `lapply`/`purrr` over `w`.

Comment: Thank you :) i will try to implement that

Answer (score 0):

The first thought I have is, do you really want to include `cbind` in

```
names <- cbind(c("w.one","w.two","w.three"))
```

since his turns `names` into a 3x1 matrix, so if `BatchGetSymbols` is generating vectors/lists of varying lengths you have a problem because they won't 'fit' in the matrix?

Suppose you removed `cbind` so that `names` is just a vector of the names you want, i.e.

```
names <- c("w.one","w.two","w.three")
```

Then you can use `assign` inside the for loop to define the new variables using whatever variable names you've defined in vector `names`:

```
for(i in 1:length(names)){
    assign(names[i], BatchGetSymbols( … ))
}
```

If you type `ls()` you now see `w.one`, `w.two` and `w.three` defined in your workspace...

I assume `BatchGetSymbols( … )` is generating lists?  If so, then these three new variables will also be defined as lists, but if vectors then you can use `as.list(BatchGetSymbols(…))` inside the for loop if you really want to force them to be lists.

Hopefully this helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you, i have removed cbind from names and will try the assign function now